# GitHub actions job with many outputs only returning one value

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am writing a Github action that includes:

- a step that gathers the diff files from PR to merge branch, and filters out the types of the files (e.g. python files, yaml files, json etc) using a script that is fully tested, and definitely working.
- the outputs of these are set using the `echo "var_name=$var_value" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` syntax (which is kind of crazy, btw github)
- The second job "needs" the first, and consumes the variables, **but only one is set**

Code below:

```yaml
env:
  GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}

jobs:
  get_changed_files:
    name: Get changed files
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      changed_files: ${{ steps.changed_files.outputs.changed_files }}
      changed_python_files: ${{ steps.changed_files.outputs.changed_python_files }}
      changed_yaml_files: ${{ steps.changed_files.outputs.changed_yaml_files }}
      changed_json_files: ${{ steps.changed_files.outputs.changed_json_files }}
      test_value: ${{ steps.changed_files.outputs.test_value }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref }}
      - name: Get changed files
        id: changed_files
        shell: bash
        run: |
          changed_files=`gh pr diff ${{ github.event.number }} --name-only | xargs`
          echo "Changed files: $changed_files"
          echo "changed_files=$changed_files" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Get changed python files
        id: changed_python_files
        shell: bash
        run: |
          cpf=`python3 ${{ github.workspace }}/deploy/_filter_files.py py ${{ steps.changed_files.outputs.changed_files }}`
          echo "Changed python files: $cpf"
          echo "changed_python_files=$cpf" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Get changed yaml files
        id: changed_yaml_files
        shell: bash
        run: |
          cyf=`python3 ${{ github.workspace }}/deploy/_filter_files.py yml ${{ steps.changed_files.outputs.changed_files }}`
          echo "Changed yaml files: $cyf"
          echo "changed_yaml_files=$cyf" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Get changed json files
        id: changed_json_files
        shell: bash
        run: |
          cjf=`python3 ${{ github.workspace }}/deploy/_filter_files.py json ${{ steps.changed_files.outputs.changed_files }}`
          echo "Changed json files: $cjf"
          echo "changed_json_files=$cjf" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Get test value
        id: test_value
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "test_value=foo" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  echo_changed_files:
    needs: get_changed_files
    name: Echo changed files
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Echo changed files
        env:
          OUTPUTS: ${{ toJson(needs.get_changed_files.outputs) }}
        run: |
          echo "All outputs: $OUTPUTS"
```

That last (for debugging only) step, _only outputs the value of `changed_files`, the others aren't even set to nulls etc.

Anyone have any ideas?  It's driving me mad!  I'm used to small issues in Github Actions, but this is very strange.

Comment: It's due to the outputs syntax in the job `outputs` field. You are using the same step as reference every time: `changed_files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have misconfigured the job outputs fields:

You are using the same **step_id** `changed_files` every time, when you should indeed update the step reference for each output using `changed_python_files`, `changed_yaml_files`, `changed_json_files`.

According to your implementation, instead of:

```
jobs:
  get_changed_files:
    name: Get changed files
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      changed_files: ${{ steps.changed_files.outputs.changed_files }}
      changed_python_files: ${{ steps.changed_files.outputs.changed_python_files }}
      changed_yaml_files: ${{ steps.changed_files.outputs.changed_yaml_files }}
      changed_json_files: ${{ steps.changed_files.outputs.changed_json_files }}
      test_value: ${{ steps.changed_files.outputs.test_value }}
```

You should use

```
jobs:
  get_changed_files:
    name: Get changed files
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      changed_files: ${{ steps.changed_files.outputs.changed_files }}
      changed_python_files: ${{ steps.changed_python_files.outputs.changed_python_files }}
      changed_yaml_files: ${{ steps.changed_yaml_files.outputs.changed_yaml_files }}
      changed_json_files: ${{ steps.changed_json_files.outputs.changed_json_files }}
     test_value: ${{ steps.test_value.outputs.test_value }}
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, thank you - I knew it was going to be a detail lost in the _quite repetitive code_ and I've been staring too long!  I've got it (mostly) working now.